# How to accept dialog in unit testing?

Tags: android, testing

I have a unit test that opens up a custom dialog and enters some text. This works, but I am unable to accept the dialog or get hold of the ok button. Please can anyone tell me how to automate the dialog acceptance using junit.

```
    ActivityMonitor activityMonitor = instrumentation.addMonitor(
            EditItem.class.getName(), null, false);

    instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
    instrumentation.invokeContextMenuAction(gridList, R.id.add, 0);

    Activity activity = instrumentation.waitForMonitorWithTimeout(
            activityMonitor, 10);
    assertNotNull("Make sure the edit item activity was called", activity);
    assertEquals("Make sure the edit item activity was called",
            EditItem.class, activity.getClass());

    final TextView nameView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.name);

            // this opens the dialog
    TouchUtils.clickView(this, nameView);

            // this adds some text
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_X);
    }

            // here I would like to accept the ok button on the dialog
```

OK I seem to have worked round this with a combination of key presses

```
    instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN);
    instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER);
```

The problem is now I can't tell when the dialog has finished being dismissed and returned to the parent Activity to continue the test with a

```
            instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
```

Go a work around for this too now:

```
            instrumentation.waitForIdleSync();
    instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
```

Seems a bit clunky, is this how you are supposed to use these tools?

Comment: I wonder if you found a good way to solve your problem (basically, getting hold of a dialog object within a ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2), because I'm facing the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.  What it looks like is that you will have to create a custom dialog.  This will allow you to retrieve the buttons you added using the findViewById().  Here is a link that I found that might get you on the right path.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/